# How can I bring out a links to collection(List), using Jsoup

Tags: java, collections, jsoup

simple question, how can I bring out a links to a list using Jsoup. I want to count all links and move them to List.

```
ReaderFactory factory = new ReaderFactory();

Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
String path = sc.nextLine();
AbstractReader reader = factory.getReader(path);

reader.read(path);
String sourceOfHtml = reader.text();

Document document = Jsoup.parse(sourceOfHtml);
Elements links = document.select("a[href]");

if(links.hasText())
    System.out.println(links);
```

Comment: `Elements extends ArrayList<Element>` so you already have list which each `Element` represents `a` tags with `href` attribute. Iterate over it like on every other list: for instance `for (Element el : links){..}`.

Comment: Thanks, I realise this, after I asked a question. Sorry 'bout that.

Comment: @Pshemo You should probably post that as an answer and sejseen should accept that (if that solves the problem). That's the way to mark a question as having been answered and not by adding "[SOLVED]" to the title. As it is now it will show up as an unanswered question.

Comment: @skyking You are right. I posted my comment as answer.

Comment: @Pshemo sorry about that. It's just that so many questions remain open that are actually solved that I thought it gave some value, while not causing any problems. Anyway, duly noted for the future.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since `Elements extends ArrayList<Element>` you already have `List` in which each `Element` represents `<a ..>` tags with `href` attribute.

To count how many elements are there you can call `size()` method.

If you want to iterate over simply use for loop like

```
for (Element el : links){
    ...
}
```